# PHP DOM Document: How to replace or change the node "default:link" into "xhtml:link" in the xml?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I tried to remove the attribute "xmlns:xhtml" from the tag "xhtml:link" with the following code:

**Source Code:**

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $url = 'android-app://com.domain.name';
    $element = $doc->createElementNS($url,'xhtml:link');

    $attribute = $doc->childNodes->item(0);

    //echo '<br>tag: '.$doc->getElementsByTagName("xhtml:link")[0];

    $element->setAttribute('href', $url);
    $element->setAttribute('rel', 'alternate');

    //echo '<pre>';print_r($element);echo '</pre>';


    $element->hasAttributeNS($url, 'xhtml');
    $element->removeAttributeNS($url, 'xhtml');

    $doc->appendChild($element);
    echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**OutPut:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <default:link href="android-app://com.domain.name" rel="alternate"/>
```

But, I am expecting the output looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xhtml:link href="android-app://com.domain.name" rel="alternate"/>
```

Please help me what I have to do? Here I struck to replace the tag...

Thanks!

Comment: But you know that the result is not valid XML? You have an undefined namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`createElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) function instead of `createElementNS`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$url = 'android-app://com.domain.name';
$element = $doc->createElement('xhtml:link');

$attribute = $doc->childNodes->item(0);

$element->setAttribute('href', $url);
$element->setAttribute('rel', 'alternate');

$doc->appendChild($element);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xhtml:link href="android-app://com.domain.name" rel="alternate"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, Chetan!